# Regex for Variable Length Text

Tags: regex, string-matching

I have two  text

`26APR -----L 22APR/0603
       BASE FARE      EQUIV AMT  TAXES/FEES/CHARGES    TOTAL
 1-   MYR1525.00      USD346.00      85.80XT       USD431.80ADT
    XT     18.20YR      16.60MY       1.00D8      50.00LK 
         1525.00         346.00      85.80            431.80TTL`

and

`27APR -----L 22APR/0702
       BASE FARE                 TAXES/FEES/CHARGES    TOTAL
2-   MYR1168.00                    378.38XT      MYR1546.38ADT
    XT     73.00MY       4.38D8      80.00YR     221.00LK 
         1168.00                    378.38           1546.38TTL`

Following is my regex .

`\s+(?<totalBase>[\d.]+)\s+(?<totalEquiv>[\d.]+)?\s*(?<totalTaxes>[\d.]+)\s+(?<totalAmount>[\d.]+)TTL\b`

the problem is that some times i have equivalent amount and some time the equivalent amount field will not be present .
Using the above  I am trying to group as totalbase , totalequiv(optional), totaltaxes and totalamount. 
Currently the values are coming whole messed up in case 2.

- totalbase =1168.00
- totalEquiv = 378.3
- totalTaxes = 8
- totalAmount = 1546.38

Comment: Try converting `\s*` into `+\s+)?` inside the group for totalEquiv. (You might put a non-grouping paren around it so the spaces won't be in the named group.)

Comment: Also, does your regex engine support `??` ? (Probably, if it does named groups.)

Comment: @AustinHastings. That worked . thank you   
' \s+(?<totalBase>[\d.]+)\s+(?<totalEquiv>[\d.]+\s+)?(?<totalTaxes>[\d.]+)\s+(?<totalAmount>[\d.]+)TTL\b'

Comment: A small issue with me now is if in case  tax value is null and but equivalent is there 
 'BASE FARE      EQUIV AMT  TAXES/FEES/CHARGES    TOTAL
 1-     USD30.00      MYR133.00                    MYR133.00INF
           30.00         133.00                       133.00TTL'
@AustinHastings
Here, the taxamount is  getting filled with equivalent amount

Comment: If you have two fields that are both optional, you have a problem. You might consider using something other than a regex to do the parsing, or you might try including spaces in the pattern, and trying to recognize `(number | so-many-spaces)` as a column.